# Android WorkManager - CoroutineWorker: Overriding coroutineContext is deprecated

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I use the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) version 2.2.0 to start a Coroutines API Call when the user gets online again.

[In the example by Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker), if I want to change the Thread of my CoroutineWorker from the default (`Dispatchers.Default`) to `Dispatchers.IO`, then I simply have to override the `val` `coroutineContext` such as:

```
class CoroutineDownloadWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
         // do some work here and return a Result
    }
}
```

But Android Studio and [the Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker#coroutinecontext) tell me, that overriding `coroutineContext` is deprecated:

[image]

What am I missing and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is in release notes:

> Deprecated CoroutineWorker.coroutineContext. This field was
>   incorrectly typed as a CoroutineDispatcher; you should no longer need
>   it as you can go to the desired coroutineContext yourself in the body
>   of the suspending function.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0-alpha01

Also there's an answer in sources:

```
/**
 * The coroutine context on which [doWork] will run. By default, this is [Dispatchers.Default].
 */
@Deprecated(message = "use withContext(...) inside doWork() instead.")
open val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default
```

So you could do the following:

`override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I `go to the desired coroutineContext in the body of the suspending function`?

Comment: @Spipau just replace `coroutineScope` with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` or any other dispatcher you need